# Missing value when pass to another class - Android - Java?

Tags: java, android

I am passing a value to another class, I get the value in another class, but when I am using the value, it shows me `0`.

```
public class MaterialSpinner extends Spinner implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

    public int widths;

    public MaterialSpinner(Context context, int width) {
        super(context);
        this.widths = width;
        // **HERE SHOW ME VALUE FOR EXAMPLE 596**
        Log.i("LOG-1", String.valueOf(widths));
        init(context, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //BUT HERE GET ME 0**
        int startX = this.widths;
        Log.i("LOG-2", String.valueOf(widths));
     }
}
```

I have other constructors:

```
public MaterialSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public MaterialSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}
```

Here is my Activity; I pass the value from here to the MaterialSpinner class:

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int width;
    int height;
    MaterialSpinner spinner1;

    private boolean shown = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        context = this;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            width = display.getWidth();
            height = display.getHeight();

        }
        else {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            width = size.x;
            height = size.y;
        }
        new MaterialSpinner(context, width);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ITEMS);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        initSpinnerHintAndFloatingLabel();
    }

    private void initSpinnerHintAndFloatingLabel() {
        spinner1 = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner1.setPaddingSafe(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have other constructors ? What happens if you print the value of `startX` ?

Comment: are you sure you don't override the value somewhere else?

Comment: Show the full code, this small snippet alone should work. Error must be somewhere else.

Comment: I am using widths just in onDraw.

Comment: My code is huge I can't show all.

Comment: @ StephaneM . Where I can show to you all of my code ?

Comment: how do you create an instance of the class? inflating from layout?

Comment: In activity I pass value :   new MaterialSpinner(context,width);

Comment: How do you add it to the Activity? Please post the code where you call `new MaterialSpinner(context,width)`, and where you add it to the Activity.

Comment: @ MC Emperor . Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating an object, you do nothing with it:

```
new MaterialSpinner(context,width);
```

in the other function you do this:

```
spinner1 = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

this will inflate the object from the `activity_start` layout. The easies way would be to create a `setWidth()` function and call it after you inflated the `View`

```
spinner1 = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
spinner1.setWidth(width);
```

EDIT: and remove `new MaterialSpinner(context,width);` since it does nothing

Comment: @ JohnnyAW . Thanks a lot for your help.